Does Perl's POD format have a specification, is this the correct behavior?
When I render the following,
=over 12

=item foo bar

baz1 baz1

baz2 baz2

=item foo bar foo bar foo bar

baz1 baz1

baz2 baz2

=back

I get,
    foo bar     baz1 baz1

                baz2 baz2

    foo bar foo bar foo bar
                baz1 baz1

                baz2 baz2

Notice how on one of the lines baz1 baz1 is pulled to the top, on the other it isn't. Is this behavior specified anywhere. The command paragraph consuming the following line if it fits within the "Indent Level" is not documented in perldoc perlpod is there another source that specifies if this is right? This is also not flagged by podchecker.

I quickly skimmed the POD chapter in the Camel book and didn't see anything of a spec. Maybe this is even up to the used translator (formatter) on how to render it.

The closest answer to "Does Perl's POD format have a specification" from the subject would be perlpodspec.  The lengthy section "About =over...=back Regions" does not exactly specify how to render your example, though. And indeed, it happens to depend on the renderer.  Using the metacpan renderer, the first baz1 baz1 line is not pulled up next to the =item line.  podview (from the Prima distribution) also does not pull it up, but sdview (from App::sdview) does, as well as perldoc in a terminal.
Which renderer did you use?

I used perldoc.

To avoid this inconsistent and unexpected behavior, change the =over line to something like:
=over 7

If the over indentLevel value is greater than the length of the item string, then you get the undesired output.
I noticed this a while back: Avoid inconsistent POD =over =item indentation
I agree that this behavior is not explicitly specified in the POD documentation.  The general consensus is that it is due to the behavior of the POD renderer.
